# Ajax double call to the same url

Tags: jquery

I have a page divided into two main blocs:

- Form to insert data
- Table listing inserted data with the possibility of making update and
  removal of records

To update/remove records, I use Jquery-Ajax as the following
**-I attchaed a script with different actions:**

```
//--first call
var a=$('#aa').val();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../folder/mypage.php",
    data: {'a':a},
    success: function(){
    }
});
//--second call
var b=$('#bb').val();
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../folder/mypage.php",
    data: {'b':b},
    success: function(){
    }
});
```

**-I created a php script (mypage.php) with both queries (update, remove) receiving sent data by ajax as the following:**

```
If ($_POST) { //---Update} else{ //---exit}
If ($_POST) { //---remove} else{ //---exit}
```

My question is the following:
Is it ok to use the same php script for both queries? or should I use 2 different scripts?

Comment: What is the problem you are getting? It is just the case of one condition check i think

Comment: I just want to know which is the best way